# Full-text search the content of ansible-doc

Tags: search, documents, ansible

I am using Ansible in an isolated network. To search for examples of a playbook, I want to do a full-text search for all the content of `ansible-doc` that is installed on the local machine.

Is there any way to do a full-text search for the content of `ansible-doc` ?

Comment: `ansible-doc` actually reads its data from the dostrings directly in the python files for all modules, libraries, plugins, collections.... installed in your environment. You can search in all those, but to be efficient you would have to parse the docstrings yourself in all configured paths.

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to grab the whole https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html via `wget -r` and then do `grep -r` on that directory and use some text based browser such as `lynx` to get to pages that match.

Alternatively you can do `grep -r <your search string>` on directory that holds your python files for all modules, libraries, plugins, collections :)